# Import-SPWeb command not working

Tags: powershell, export, import, web

Trying to import one subsite from one site to other exported the site successfully using

```
Export-SPWeb –Identity http://sitename -Path E:\backups\site.cmp
```

but when trying to import using the below command

```
Import-SPWeb https://newsitename -Path "E:\backups\site.cmp" –UpdateVersions:Overwrite
```

i am getting below error as shown in screen shot 
[image]

Comment: add the Identity parameter before URL, and remove semicolon between updateversions and overwrite

Comment: new site is already created or not? also try to put -identity parameter in it.

Comment: Hi Waqas it is not created.The site am trying to import is HH and I want it to be same name so do i need to create a site on HH into before I do import?

Comment: try to create the new site collection first without any template. is it site collection or subsite?

Comment: Hi JayHell I tried using the -Identity and removing semicolon b/w updateversions and overwrite but I get different error now saying URL doesnot exists

Comment: waqas it is a sub site

Comment: ok create a new subsite on that path( where you trying to restore) then run the import command

Comment: create a subsite without any template then it will save u from tons of things... like this New-SPWeb http://sitename  dont assign any template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40235/discussion-between-user2314241-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run the import command, you have to make sure couple of things.

1. Make sure destination site collection / subsite should be created 1st. Iw ould prefer to create it using powerShell without assigning any template. `New-SPWeb http://sitename`
2. Now run the Import command.

Comment: thanks waqas that was simply perfect solution without any hiccups you are the savior!